# Not being able to click a link next to a fixed div.

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, fixed

**EDIT:** Problem is solved.. I can't believe I didn't think about that to begin with.
Solution:

`#message-box{position:fixed;bottom: 29px;left:0px;width: 400px;}`

---- Original message :

Hi,

Here is the image:
http://i242.photobucket.com/albums/ff198/Warz/divchatproblemmodified.png

(it says id=footer there but its supposed to say `id=footerbar`. Also the bar in the very bottom (where you enter a message, with an id called "statusbar" ) should cover `width: 100%;` as it already does. )

I'm trying to create a bottom bar on my site with chat. The chat size should be possible to resize (change height). As you can see, I placed a div (msg-top) above the chat, which means, when chat is resized the `msg-top` should also be moved.

If you take a look at the following image you will see the problem. The `<div id="footerbar">` has following settings and hence cover the entire area:

```
#footerbar {position: fixed;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;}
```

**All** the divs are children of `#footerbar`.

Because of this, if I resize the chat box to height 100% no links can be clicked. Even with small height like on the picture, all links to the right of chat box cannot be clicked...

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

The other divs:

```
/* background opacity */
#opacity-me,#msg-top,#msg-messages,#statusbar {
  background: black;
  color: white; 
  border-top: dotted 1px white;
  opacity: .90;    
  filter: alpha(opacity="90");
  z-index: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#statusbar {
  position: relative;
}
#message-box{
  position:relative; 
  width: 400px;
}
#msg-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px;
  border: dotted 1px white;
}
#msg-messages {
  padding-left: 4px;    
  padding-right: 4px;    
  height: 100px;    
  border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Element is below another Element, so you're not able to klick the Link, the Link is still working... just use z-index on footerbar or try to change the footerbar position...

Answer (score 0):

give the div id=footer a height, so something like:

```
#footerbar {position: fixed;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px; height:30px;}
```

this should fix it, just adjust the height accordingly. let me know if this works.

Comment: That doesn't work because if I set height to for instance 30px the chat+bar+msg-top in total can not be more than 30px. It looks like it's all pushed out of the screen.